# CandidateResume' class is not supported for deserialization of an array

Tags: c#, arrays, json, asp.net-mvc-4

I am trying deserialization array bellow this way but  i am getting that error.

```
JavaScriptSerializer jsSerializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
var myobj = jsSerializer.Deserialize<CandidateResume[]>(json);
```

This is my json file

```
[
   [
      {
         "name":"Riaz Kabir",
         "url":"https://recruit.theladders.com/resumeviewer?jobseekerId=01-sid-BDLBKUPMIL6HGZ22MOAJJIWYGE",
         "summary":"ASP.NET MVC Developer Hewlett-Packard (HP) (1/2013-Present) Location: Schenectady, NY Compensation: $50k+ Previous Titles/Companies: 2016 ►",
         "role":"ASP.NET MVC Developer at Hewlett-Packard (HP)",
         "compensation":"$50k+",
         "education":"BS, Computer Science and Engineering, Asian University of Bangladesh",
         "expertise":"Databases , IT Consulting , Software Development , Front End Development",
         "years":"Less than 5",
         "relocation":"Schenectady, NY Within 1000 miles of 12305 Would need to relocate here",
         "resume":"0M8R4KGxGuEAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAP",
         "resumeExtension":"doc",
         "resumeMimeType":"application/msword"
      }
   ]
]
```

Bellow my candidate Resume class

```
public class CandidateResume
        {

            public string name { get; set; }
            public string url { get; set; }
            public string summary { get; set; }
            public string role { get; set; }
            public string compensation { get; set; }
            public string education { get; set; }
            public string expertise { get; set; }
            public string years { get; set; }
            public string relocation { get; set; }
            public string resume { get; set; }
            public string resumeExtension { get; set; }
            public string resumeMimeType { get; set; }

        }
```

Error Message: CandidateResume' is not supported for deserialization of an array.

Comment: Also I am trying this way , i am getting same error 
 JavaScriptSerializer jsSerializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
                var myobj = jsSerializer.Deserialize<List<CandidateResume>>(json);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your JSON is a list of a list. Think about the error `CandidateResume is not supported for deserialization of an array.` It's trying to deserialize an array to a `CandidateResume` object.

Instead try:

```
var myobj = jsSerializer.Deserialize<List<List<CandidateResume>>>(json);
```

Or change your JSON to not be a list of a list.

Answer (score 0):

In json you have extra '[' and ']'. Just remove them.
Or if it is not acceprtable you can try

```
var myobj = jsSerializer.Deserialize<CandidateResume[][]>(json);
```